# identifier mapping has wrong number of columns:

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

can anyone help me 
i have this error 
caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: identifier mapping has wrong number of columns: com.twins.FootFans.model.MemberAllTeam type: component[allTeam,member]

```
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "team_id", referencedColumnName = "teamId")
private Team allTeam;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "identifier_AllTeam" ,referencedColumnName ="identifier" ),
    @JoinColumn(name = "connectionType_AllTeam" ,referencedColumnName ="connectionType") 
} )

private Member member;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: i want to add a extrat column to a jointable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `@Id` before `@ManyToOne`. for more refer bellow link

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/UseTwoJoinedColumnsforManytooneMapping.htm

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/ManyToOneSetJoinColumnName.htm